# SQLITE3 inserting a null value

Tags: ios4, sqlite, ipad

```
sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, nil);
```

How can I add a `null` in my above statement , as I am making this field auto increment.

Here's my code :

```
if (sqlite3_open([[self dataFilePath] UTF8String], &database)!= SQLITE_OK) 
 {
 sqlite3_close(database);
 NSAssert(0, @"Failed to open database");
 }
NSLog(@"json count ========== %i",[jsonArray count]);
    for (int i =0 ; i < [jsonArray count]; i++) 
    // while (i < [jsonArray count])
{ 
 dictionary = [jsonArray objectAtIndex:i];
 char *errorMsg;

 sqlite3_stmt *statement;
 if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [insertQuery UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) 
 {
 // NSLog(@"%@",[dictionary valueForKey:@"text"]);
 sqlite3_bind_null(statement, 1);
 sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [[dictionary valueForKey:@"date"] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
    // NSLog(@"date %@",[dictionary valueForKey:@"date"]);

 sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [[dictionary valueForKey:@"text"] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
    // NSLog(@"text %@",[dictionary valueForKey:@"text"]);

 }
 if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error updating table: %s", errorMsg); 
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
 sqlite3_close(database);
 }
```

To select :

```
sqlite3 *database;
if (sqlite3_open([[self dataFilePath] UTF8String], &database)
    != SQLITE_OK) { sqlite3_close(database);
    NSAssert(0, @"Failed to open database");
}
NSString *query = [self selectQueryInDB];
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String],
                       -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) 
    { 
        int row = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);

        if (row == indexPathRow+1) 
        {
            char *field1 = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
            char *field2 = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);
            NSString *f1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:field1];

            NSString *f2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:field2];

            NSString *fullData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",f1,f2];
            NSLog(@"%@",fullData);
        }

    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
sqlite3_close(database);
```

I am getting SIGABRT in NSString *f1 as `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSPlaceholderString initWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString'`
Please tell me what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 6):

`sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, nil)` will bind 0 to the first bind point, not NULL. 0 and NULL are not the same things in SQL.

I think you're looking for `sqlite3_bind_null`. It binds NULL to a bind point, as in:

```
sqlite3_bind_null(statement, 1);
```

There's no parameter here for NULL; it's in the name of the function.

Also, unbound parameters default to NULL. So unless you're using `sqlite3_reset`, you shouldn't need to use this at all.

(Since we're on the topic of bindings and resets, I should mention `sqlite3_clear_bindings`, which binds **all** parameters to NULL.)

**Problem 2**

You updated this to mention a SIGABRT in the NSString *f1 line.

There's two problems with your code that I see:

1. `sqlite3_column_text` is 0 based; the first column is 0, not 1. (Yes, columns are 0 based. Even though bindings are 1-based.)

   ```
   char *field1 = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
   ```

   should be:

   ```
   char *field1 = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
   ```
2. `sqlite3_column_text` can return `NULL` if `NULL` is in the data, but `initWithUTF8String:` does not accept `NULL` as a value.

I suggest doing this:

```
NSString *f1 = field1 ? [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:field1] : nil;
```

Using this, you'll end up with a nil `NSString` if you had a `NULL` column in the data. You can make decisions on this, and it's easy to do `f1 ?: @""` when you really need a string.

Another approach is to change the query:

```
SELECT Field FROM Table;
```

To:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Field,'') FROM Table;
```

You'll no longer be able to tell if Field was originally `NULL`, but maybe you don't care.